# Rejection of papers after a long time

Tags: publications, paper-submission, rejection

I have already submitted a manuscript to an outstanding math journal. It is under review for about 9 months. I would like to know about the probability of rejection of a paper after 9 months?

Comment: The paper probably won't get a desk reject at this stage, assuming some competency. But, beyond that, it's difficult to comment.

Comment: 1) As a cultural norm, mathematicians are encouraged to recommend rejection quickly if they don't think the claimed results of a paper are good enough or important enough to be published in the journal in question.  2) Some journals, particularly high prestige journals, have a two-stage process where they first ask an expert to determine if the paper is important enough before having the paper undergo an actual review.  3) Of course papers can still be rejected after "real review", for example if the writing is bad or the mathematics is actually wrong.

Comment: Did you by chance just sent a gentle email to the Editor in Chief asking about the status of the manuscript? Sometimes they procrastinate like any human being and forget to remind the reviewers to complete their reviews on time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Editor would have rejected it immediately, if it was clearly unsuitable. Though sometimes editors do make mistakes.

Now it is up to the reviewers and the editor. Nine months is not an alarmingly long time. I would not make any deductions based on how long the paper has been under review.